# How to set a Mapkit Overlay object's "zPosition"? (i.e. how to access it's view layer?)

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay

How can I access & set the `layer.zPosition` property of a Mapkit overlay?

For example how to do this:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
   let layer = overlay.layer // ??? HOW TO DO THIS
   layer.zPosition = 1
}
```

Or is there another way?

BACKGROUND: Want an approach to group the `MapKitView` overlays I have have to determine what types of objects get displays on top of other types of objects ?